# using word_delimiter with edgeNGram ignores Word_Delimiter Token

Tags: elasticsearch

I have my custom analyzer as below. But I dont understand how to achieve my goal.

My goal is that I want to have whitespace separated inverted index but also I want to have autocomplete feature after user enters min 3 chars. For that I though to combine word_delimiter and edgeNGram tokens as below

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "my_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
              "standard",
              "lowercase",
              "my_word_delimiter",
              "my_edge_ngram_analyzer"
            ],
            "type": "custom"
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "my_word_delimiter": {
            "catenate_all": true,
            "type": "word_delimiter"
          },
          "my_edge_ngram_analyzer": {
            "min_gram": 3,
            "max_gram": 10,
            "type": "edgeNGram"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will give result for "Brother TN-200" as below. But I was expecting "tn" to be also in the reverted index as I have word_delimiter token. why is it not in the inverted index? How can I achieve this?

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/myIndex/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pr
    etty=true" -d "Brother TN-200"
    {
      {
        "token" : "bro",
        "start_offset" : 14,
        "end_offset" : 21,
        "type" : "word",
        "position" : 2
      }, {
        "token" : "brot",
        "start_offset" : 14,
        "end_offset" : 21,
        "type" : "word",
        "position" : 2
      }, {
        "token" : "broth",
        "start_offset" : 14,
        "end_offset" : 21,
        "type" : "word",
        "position" : 2
      }, {
        "token" : "brothe",
        "start_offset" : 14,
        "end_offset" : 21,
        "type" : "word",
        "position" : 2
      }, {
        "token" : "brother",
        "start_offset" : 14,
        "end_offset" : 21,
        "type" : "word",
        "position" : 2
      }, {
        "token" : "tn2",
        "start_offset" : 22,
        "end_offset" : 28,
        "type" : "word",
        "position" : 3
      }, {
        "token" : "tn20",
        "start_offset" : 22,
        "end_offset" : 28,
        "type" : "word",
        "position" : 3
      }, {
        "token" : "tn200",
        "start_offset" : 22,
        "end_offset" : 28,
        "type" : "word",
        "position" : 3
      }, {
        "token" : "200",
        "start_offset" : 25,
        "end_offset" : 28,
        "type" : "word",
        "position" : 4
      }]
    }
```

UPDATE:

of course, if I use  "min_gram": 2, "tn" will be in the reverted index but I dont want this because if any other word consists "tn" inside the word, it will appear in the result list.
For example about "hp" keyword. I am getting products for "Hewlett Packard" as my products are like "hp xxx" but I get also a product called "tech hpc". I dont want this product to be displayed until I type "hpc". Thats the reason I set 3.

If i dont use edgeNGram tokenizer but only word_delimiter, "tn" is in the inverted index as Brother TN-200 will be indexed as brother, tn and 200. that's why I expected that word_delimiter makes the "tn" to be in the inverted index. Does it have no use if I use it with edgeNGram? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `my_edge_ngram_analyzer` the  `min_gram` setting is 3 as a result any Token with length less than 3 codepoints would not show up.
You would need to set this to 2 if you would want `TN` to show up.

Example:

```
get <my_index>/_analyze?tokenizer=whitespace&filters=my_edge_ngram_analyzer&text=TN
```

The above call would return 0 tokens.

Comment: yes, i know it should be 2 but I preferred 3 because I dont want if any other product consists "tn" should show up in the results list. For example about "hp". I am getting products for "Hewlett Packard" as my products are like "hp xxx" but I get also a product called "tech hpc". I dont want this product to be displayed until i type "hpc".

Comment: On the other hands, If i dont use edgeNGram tokenizer but only  word_delimiter, "tn" is in the inverted index. thats why I expected that word_delimiter makes the "tn" to be indexed. Does it have no use if I use it with edgeNGram?

Comment: if the word-delimiter filter produces tokens of 2 or less codepoints they are ignored by `my-edge-ngram` just like it would ignore any tokens of  2 or less if the word-delimiter wasn't there .  Also i don't see why you would get "hewlett packard" when you type "hp" for a product "hp xxx" . `my_edge_ngram`  should remove "hp" from inverted index and only `hpc` would remain `curl -Xget "http://<localhost>/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&text=hp xxx"`

Comment: One way around is to create two [views](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html)   of the field while indexing, one analyzed  without edge-ngram and another with edge-ngram filter and do a `should match` of the two and provide higher boost to the former clause. This way `hp/ tn` would show up and you  would  get autocomplete on 3 or less characters

Comment: about hp, i meant that when I set  "min_gram": 2, but you made it clear why it doesnt work. I will try your suggestion and let you know. thanks